# Why are <input> element ID's repeating in nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

```
class User
    has_one :user_profile
end
class UserProfile
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I am rendering a form for editing using partials.

The views are:

```
user_profile/edit.html.erb
--------------------------
<%= render 'form' %>

user_profile/_form.html.erb
---------------------------
<%= form_for @user_profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @user_profile do |builder| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'user_profiles/fields', :locals => { :f => builder } %>
    # id is correct i.e. [user_profile][last_name] for the field below 
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


user_profile/_fields.html.erb
-----------------------------
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>

# id's for the above fields are rendered as:
# user_profile[user_profile][first_name]
# notice the second repeated [user_profile]
```

How do I fix it so that the id's come out as `user_profile[first_name]` instead of `user_profile[user_profile][first_name]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) it's:

> suitable for specifying additional model objects in the same form.

With an example showing this paradigm:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  First name: <%= person_form.text_field :first_name %>
  Last name : <%= person_form.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= fields_for @person.permission do |permission_fields| %>
    Admin?  : <%= permission_fields.check_box :admin %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Notice `form_for @person` and `fields_for @person.permission` - fields_for should be used for an association of a model, form_for should be used for the model itself. The reason your html is rendering as `user_profile[user_profile]` is that you're specifying `@user_profile` in both `form_for` and `fields_for`.

You likely need to change the parameter in `form_for` to @user (or the equivalent variable you have in scope). This will make your output html:

```
user[user_profile][first_name]
```

which you can pass to UsersController#update as long as User `accepts_nested_attributes_for` user_profile.  If you want to instead pass the parameter hash from the form to UserProfilesController#update, then you want to drop the `fields_for` entirely and just render the fields under `form_for @user_profile` - which will give you html like `user_profile[first_name]`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I will re-think how I'm using partials in my app.